# Moving/copying to Windows 8 Storage Spaces parity pool, slows to a halt every time after Windows 8.1 upgrade

Tags: external-hard-drive, freeze, windows-8.1-upgrade, storage-spaces

I recently set up Windows 8 with an external (USB) storage space parity pool (4 drives, varying sizes 1.5&2TB drives). I managed to move about 3TB to this pool without a hitch, then the Windows 8.1 upgrade popped up and I thought sure. I upgraded and then next day tried to move another 1TB to the space (have used about 3TB of 6.4TB available space) and it started off fine, but then started slowing down to the point that it came to a halt (after about 2GB were copied) and locked up my system.

I had to reboot and tried again, but it locked up again. I then tried moving *from* this pool and that worked OK. I tried to write to *another* pool (consisting of internal drives) and no problem. I tried again to write to this external pool, and it locked up. This is driving me nuts, as I have about 3TB of storage that I intended to use but can't. I checked the drives in the **Storage Spaces** window, and all the physical drives are fine, there were no warnings of any kind. I've got no ideas left, so any help would really really be appreciated!

Comment: You sure its just no the drives in question?  The overall speed of the storage space will be limited by the drives.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realize that the speed will slow down the less space I have when using parity however I have barely used half of the total space and my system freezes. That and my system isn't just slowing down, its stopping, then freezing. And storage spaces is giving me no warnings. Actually all the drives in this pool are around 65% used according to the storage spaces window.

Comment: Again.  Are you sure all of the HDDs are working.  The type of issue your running into indicates a hardware problem not software.

Comment: Well I am not positive no. But, they were all working fine individually when i installed them, they were working fine when i was moving files to them/the-pool, and windows has not indicated that there are any problems with the individual drives. I guess I can find a drive utility to check them out but all other things seem to be pointing towards the drives being ok. A new observation though, I have tried transferring a relatively large number of files in small chunks and have so far been able to transfer over 10gb in ~500mb chunks but it still freezes if i try multiple GBs at a time.

Comment: Another observation. I installed Terra copy and it froze up instantly. I then tried disabling the "system cache" option and viola! (kinda) it seems to copy without freezing, albeit it is still glacially slow. Any further thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Either way, parity spaces is completely useless. Anyone reading this, please cast your vote for the request:

[ZFS on Windows Server](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/295056-storage/suggestions/10403058-zfs-on-windows-server)